# How do I fix "<attribute> is not a retrieved facet" in Algolia's react-instantsearch connectedRange slider?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm using a range slider with `react-instantsearch`, and I'm attempting to control the `attributeName` prop with a variable in my component's state.

The slider (the code of which is below) is called from the parent component like so:

```
<InstantSearch
    appId='etc'
    apiKey='etc etc'
    indexName='etc'
 >
    <InstantSearchSlider
        updatePriceAttributeName={this.props.updatePriceAttributeName}
        min={this.props.min}
        max={this.props.max}
        attributeName={this.state.currentAttributeName}
     />
</InstantSearch>
```

However, when I change the `currentAttributeName` value in `state`, I'm met with this error:

```
Uncaught Error: prices.hourly.ten is not a retrieved facet.
    at SearchResults../node_modules/algoliasearch-helper/src/SearchResults/index.js.SearchResults.getFacetValues (index.js:640)
    at ProxyComponent.getProvidedProps (connectRange.js:119)
    at ProxyComponent.getProvidedProps (createConnector.js:259)
    at ProxyComponent.componentWillReceiveProps (createConnector.js:168)
    at ProxyComponent.componentWillReceiveProps (createPrototypeProxy.js:44)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:610
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:609)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:546)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:124)
```

I'd like my users to pick one attribute from a list of possible attributes. Is there a way to do that?

```
// InstantSearchSlider.js
// nearly a full copy/paste from algolia docs, but with a different slider component

class Range extends Component<Props, State> {
    static defaultProps = {
        refine: minMax => minMax
    };
    state = { currentValues: { min: this.props.min, max: this.props.max } };

    componentWillReceiveProps(sliderState) {
      if (sliderState.canRefine) {
        this.setState({
            currentValues: {
                min: sliderState.currentRefinement.min,
                max: sliderState.currentRefinement.max
            }
        });
        }
    }

    onValuesUpdated = sliderState => {
        this.setState({
            currentValues: {
                min: sliderState[0],
                max: sliderState[1]
            }
        });
    };

    onChange = sliderState => {
        console.log(sliderState);
        if (
            this.props.currentRefinement.min !== sliderState[0] ||
            this.props.currentRefinement.max !== sliderState[1]
        ) {
            this.props.refine({
                min: sliderState[0],
                max: sliderState[1]
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { min, max, currentRefinement } = this.props;
        const { currentValues } = this.state;
        return min !== max
            ? <div>
                  <PackageSelector handleUpdate={this.props.updatePriceAttributeName} />
                  <Slider
                      range
                      defaultValue={[min, max]}
                      min={min}
                      max={max}
                      value={[currentRefinement.min, currentRefinement.max]}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      onAfterChange={this.onValuesUpdated}
                  />
                  {/* <Rheostat
                      min={min}
                      max={max}
                      values={[currentRefinement.min, currentRefinement.max]}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      onValuesUpdated={this.onValuesUpdated}
                  /> */}
                  <div
                      style={{
                          display: 'flex',
                          justifyContent: 'space-between'
                      }}
                  >
                      <div>
                          {currentValues.min}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                          {currentValues.max}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            : null;
    }
}

export default connectRange(Range);
```

**ETA**: this error also occurs when I try make instantsearch widgets hidden on initial render, revealing them after user interaction (e.g., in a collapsible `div`). I imagine this means the issue isn't tied directly to state, but I'm not sure enough about what it is to update the title yet.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I tried to reproduce your issue but didn't succeed. Could you update this codesandebox with your code to show the issue? https://codesandbox.io/s/p5704rpjpj

Comment: can you `console.log` `updatePriceAttributeName`, `min`, `max`, `attributeName` when you see the error.

Comment: @Marie thank you for asking me to do that. In trying to reproduce it, I realized that this problem is only occurring on my index, not on the bestbuy index from the tutorial. I'll update once I figure out the precise reason.

Comment: @Brandon can you check that `prices.hourly.ten` is present as an attributesForFacetting in your dashboard?

Comment: Maybe that attribute isn't present in all of the records @AbhinavJain?

Comment: @Marie I seem to have figured it out--explained it in my answer, but tl;dr is that attributes missing from `attributesForFaceting` _was_ the problem, but I also had to remove a hard-coded min/max prop from the slider component once I'd added the attributes to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Marie from Algolia for helping me here.

The error was the result of a cascading series of problems.

The attributes I was trying to set on the `RangeSlider` were not in `attributesForFaceting` in the dash. I added them, but this didn't immediately fix the problem.

Previous to adding them, the slider *worked*, but it wasn't auto-calculating min/max (and no errors were thrown), so I just hard-coded min/max.

It appears, though, that hard-coded min/max break the slider when I tried to swap `attributeNames`, irrespective of whether the values were in `attributesForFaceting`.

So, I removed the hard-coded min/max, and, since I'd added the attributes to `attributesForFaceting`, the min/max were calculated correctly and I was able to swap between attributes just fine.